Linux read() occasionally returns "No child processes" (errno 10) when reading perf counters after kernel update
I have C++ program that collects hardware counters using the perf_event_open and read methods on CentOS9 Stream.
The code was working perfectly fine with kernel version 5.14.0-319.el9.x86_64. After a kernel update to 5.14.0-472.el9.x86_64, the read method occasionally returns -1. I haven't been able to find the cause, it seems random when it happens. Sometimes I'm able to collect hundreds of samples before I encounter this error, and other times only 20 or so. Sometimes the program runs error free.
I store the errno value immediately after the read(). The value is 10. Then, I call strerror_r to print its description, which is "No child processes".
This is an example of how I initialize the hardware counters:
#define TOTAL_HW_COUNTERS 4
const char * pmu_names[TOTAL_HW_COUNTERS] = {"instructions", "cpu-cycles", "branch-misses","cache-misses"};
unsigned int pmu_offsets[TOTAL_HW_COUNTERS] = {PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS, PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES, PERF_COUNT_HW_BRANCH_MISSES, PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MISSES};
unsigned int pmu_types[TOTAL_HW_COUNTERS] = {PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE, PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE, PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE, PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE};

int initializePerf(pid_t child_pid) {
    static struct perf_event_attr pe;
    int fd;

    /* The first object is the leader */
    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(pe));
    pe.type = pmu_types[0];
    pe.size = sizeof(pe);
    pe.config = pmu_offsets[0];
    pe.disabled = 1;
    pe.inherit = 1;
    pe.exclude_kernel = 0;
    pe.exclude_hv = 0;
    pe.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;
    fd = perf_event_open(&pe, child_pid, -1, -1, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        int errsv = errno;
        std::cerr << "Error opening leader " << pe.config << " errno: " << errsv << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* Add the rest of the perf_event_attr objects in a group with the leader */
    for (int i = 1; i < TOTAL_HW_COUNTERS; i++) {
        memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(pe));
        pe.type = pmu_types[i];
        pe.size = sizeof(pe);
        pe.config = pmu_offsets[i];
        pe.disabled = 1;
        pe.inherit = 1;
        pe.exclude_kernel = 0;
        pe.exclude_hv = 0;
        pe.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;

        if (perf_event_open(&pe, child_pid, -1, fd, 0) == -1) {
            int errsv = errno;
            std::cerr << "Error opening group counter " << pe.config << " errno: " << errsv << std::endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    return fd;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    initializePerf(0);
    // Do stuff
    return 0;
}

I have a thread that wakes up every 100ms to reset the counter values and uses this method to read hardware counters and store all samples in read_pmu_buf.
int readPerfCounters(int bytes_read, char * read_pmu_buf, int fd, int count) {
    char * bufptr = read_pmu_buf + bytes_read;
    int errsv;
    int size_read = read(fd, bufptr, count);
    errsv = errno;
    if (size_read == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Error reading perf counters at fd " << fd;
        std::cerr << " errno: " << errsv << std::endl;
        char buffer[ 256 ];
        char * errorMsg = strerror_r(errsv, buffer, 256 );
        std::cerr << errorMsg << std::endl; // Output: "No child processes"

    }
    return size_read;
}

Since this happened only after I updated the kernel, I tried a slightly older version than 5.14.0-472.el9.x86_64, 5.14.0-467.el9.x86_64, but the error behavior is still the same.
The error is definitely coming from the read() call, but I don't understand: (1) how is "No child processes" related to a read()? And (2) what changed between kernel versions?

I am guessing that CentOS / RedHat might have backported perf: Disallow mis-matched inherited group reads from the v6.6 kernel. Try grepping ECHILD in "kernel/events/core.c" in the CentOS kernel source.

@IanAbbott, I do not see the core.c file inside kernel/events/ all I see is a Makefile. I did grep and found group_generation in lnclude/linux/perf_event.h (which was also added in the commit you pointed out). This suggests that your guess is correct. In that case, I still don't understand the issue and why I only see it in some reads but not all of them. Do you have suggestions on changing my code to avoid this issue? Or suggestions for the correct error handling on my end when I encounter it?

I have no suggestions, sorry.
